# How do you create a single page web application using Dojo 1.10?

Tags: dojo

I found several examples on how to create a single page app but I'm not sure which path to take.  My web app is purely desktop browser based - mobile support isn't required.

One was using [dojox/app](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojox/app.html)  (but this says for mobile app primarily - can it be used for desktop app with full support for everything from standard dojo including desktop widgets and functionality? )

Another was using this example [Dojorama](http://sirprize.me/scribble/dojorama-introduction-building-a-dojo-single-page-application/)

I also found this example  [Dojomat](https://github.com/sirprize/dojomat)

Is there a recommended way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here an example / getting started app i did a while back that's been blessed by the dojo folks. https://github.com/denov/dojo-demo

Comment: In main.js the comments mention a file called run.js, what is this, I don't see it in the folders.  Also  - what is app.config.js for?  I didn't include this and the app still works fine.

Comment: it looks like the run.js is some odd cruff that needs to be removed or updated.  thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: are you asking about app.profile.js?  if so it's used to create a build.  https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/build/buildSystem.html

Comment: In postCreate (and also changeScreens) properties of HomePage.js I don't understand the use of var that = this. For example why couldn't you just use this.ChangeScreens inside topic.Subscribe() of postCreate? I know it won't work using 'this', but why?  EDIT:  I think I found the answer in dojo/_base/lang documentation regarding use of hitch() to force the function to retain its original context

Comment: in a lot js code you see things like var that = this or var _this = this.  this is done to bring in this into the local scope of functions that defined in the same scope of the that variable.   as if you reference this inside a function it will be this of the function and not 'outer' this.  hopefully this makes sense..  dojo does provide lang.hitch() which is very handy.

Comment: @denov How does the loader know to load only the main.js at the start, since the 'app' folder contains two possible modules - HomePage and main.  Or does it load both?

Comment: @erotavlas - the magic happens on line #55 of index.html. it only loads main.js. if you look at main.js you'll see it loading HomePage.js

details can be found at https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/modules_advanced/

Answer (score 1):

I don't have great experience of working with Dojo Toolkit, but I make this steps on my projects:

- create the layouts for application:

  ```
  <body class="claro">
      <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/LayoutContainer">
          <div data-dojo-type="app/MainMenu" data-dojo-props="region: 'center'"></div>
          <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentContainer" id="contentContainer"></div>
      </div>
  </body>
  ```
- now I register routes, and when hash changes, I check `contentContainer`:

  ```
  var self = this;

  if (this.content){
      this.content.destroyRecursive(); // Dijit widget method
  }

  require([
      pathToApplicationModule // Maked as dedicated widget
  ], function (Widget){
      self.content = new Widget();
      self.content.placeAt(registry.byId("contentContainer");    
      self.content.startup();
  });
  ```
- every part of application is Widget, for example:

  ```
  define([
      "dojo/_base/declare",
      "dijit/_WidgetBase",
      "dijit/_TemplatedMixin",
      "dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin",
      "dojo/text!./templates/MainMenu.html",
      "dijit/MenuBar",
      "dijit/MenuItem"
  ], function (
      declare,
      WidgetBase,
      TemplatedMixin,
      WidgetsInTemplateMixin,
      template
  ){
      return declare("app.MainMenu", [
          WidgetBase,
          TemplatedMixin,
          WidgetsInTemplateMixin
      ], {
          // Here main menu properties: template, actions, etc.
      });
  });
  ```

What about user permissions? I don't know. Maybe, loading via AJAX.